# Making a database scalable

Tags: php, mysql, caching, scalability

I've been developing a website for some time now and so far everything is fast and good, though that is with one active user. I don't know how many people will use my website in the first, week, month or year.

I've been looking into what scaling means and how to achieve it and caching seems to be a big part of it. So I started searching for ways to cache my content. Currently I've just developed the website in XAMPP. I'm using MySQL for the database and simple PHP with MySQLi to edit the data. I also do some simply logging with the built-in System Messages app in OS X Mountain Lion. So I'm thinking about using [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) for the caching.

Is this a good approach?

How can I test it to really see the difference?

How do I know that it will work great even with many more users?

Are there any good benchmarking apps out there?

Comment: Is there an issue? Also, please focus on *one* question. The only somewhat interesting bit is "How can I test the scalability of my Database/Model/Cache?"

Comment: @pst Not at the moment. But as I said, there is currently only one user. How do I know that it works this great with thousands of users? Yeah "How can I test the scalability of my Database/Model/Cache?" is mostly my question.

Comment: When you have thousands of users you'll have thousands of users. But that is not now. Nor is it many. Millions, okay, that's a good bit. Start with a *clean normalized schema* .. if there is a performance issue there will be time/money/reason to put into it [later]. Things like caching can generally by added later or as part of a separate service model - no big deal. If you don't *need* horizontal scalability, vertical scalability on commodity hardware can go a *long* way with a good schema. (If you do need mass horizontal scalability, look at the "examples" like Twitter.)

Comment: But shouldn't a database be prepared for millions of users? Isn't that what scaling is all about?

Comment: Should a motorcycle be prepared for 20 passengers? Not if my friend and I are the only ones who'll ride it. If later, I find the need for 20 passengers, I'll buy a VW minibus .. that's a poor analogy though, because RDBMS *can* and *do* scale well for practical numbers without "getting all fancy".

Comment: That was a great example :) Though it can't be bad to prepare it for potential users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get and Use [jMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/).

with jMeter you can test how quick responses are coming back and how pages are loading in addition to confirming that there aren't any errors currently going on.  This way you can simulate a ton of load; while seeing actual performance updates when making an adjustment such as using memcache.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to make sure that a database scales well, but I think the most important part is that you define proper indexes for your tables. *At least* the fields that are foreign keys should have an index defined.

For example, if you have a large forum, you might have a table of topics that looks like this:

```
topic_id | name
---------+--------------------------------
       1 | "My first topic!"
       2 | "Important topic"
       3 | "I really like to make topics!"
     ... | ...
 7234723 | "We have a lot of topics!"
```

And then another table with the actual posts in the topics:

```
post_id  | user       | topic_id
---------+------------+---------
       1 | "Spammer"  | 1
       2 | "Erfa"     | 2
       3 | "Erfa"     | 1
       4 | "Spammer"  | 1
     ... | ...        | ...
87342352 | "Erfa"     | 457454
```

When you load a topic in your application, you want to load all posts that match the topic id. In this case, you cannot afford to look through all database rows, because there are simply too many! Fortunately, you do not have to do much to make sure this is done, you just have to create an index for the field topic_id and you are done.

This is a very basic thing to do to make your database scale well, but since it is so important, I really thought someone should mention it!